# Add a view shadow on android with appcelerator

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

i tried to put a shadow to my view on android, but i failed. I need to have a simply shadow like [image: image of the desired result] (and like iOS viewShadow property):

Answer (score 3):

For Android you can use the Material Design cardviews, you can read about it here: http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2015/11/titanium-5-1-0-sample-app/ which includes a sample app.

Documentation here: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Android.CardView

```
var card = Ti.UI.Android.createCardView({
    contentPadding: 20,
    cardCornerRadius: 10,
    cardUseCompatPadding: true
});
```

Most importantly, use the `elevation` property: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Android.CardView-property-elevation

This requires TiSDK 5.1.2 or higher, which was released yesterday

Comment: that's very good but i saw that a very good shadow work only with 5.1 android version :( how can i do a good shadow in android sdks below?

Comment: cardview will work on all Android SDK's. The 5.1 version you see is Titanium SDK

Comment: some property don't work on old android version. From the documentation, for example the elevation property:

elevation : Number
Elevation for CardView.

**Requires: Android 5 and later**

Comment: correct, but there is a replacement build for you, see this screenshot which is linked in the blogpost: https://s3.amazonaws.com/www.appcelerator.com.images/fokke-ti510-cardview.png